# How to resolve the issue when I want to show multiple videos in Skype by using bots

Tags: bots, botframework

I am working on bots project using the BotFramework in that I am using some videos to displaying in bots and here the issue is when I am displaying the videos in the local it's working properly and when I am configuring to Skype, it shows only one video in Skype.

The code is like this:

```
private async void TrailersList(IDialogContext context, Activity message)
{
        Activity replyToConversation = message.CreateReply("Welcome to **MyApp**." + "(Hi)");
        replyToConversation.Recipient = message.From;
        replyToConversation.Type = "message";
        replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        Dictionary<string, string> cardContentList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        cardContentList.Add("Jason Bourne", "");
        cardContentList.Add("The Land", "");
        cardContentList.Add("Yoga Hosers", "");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> cardContent in cardContentList)
        {
            if (cardContent.Key == "Jason Bourne")
            {
                replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
                {
                                                                ContentUrl= "https://ce5qxa-bn1306.files.1drv.com/y3m9N1SkzBRmwSTd_OZgBWhsAVBzHi5ij025q-W0Cy_6CHHvm8brMaawS-yx8_MhbmdRsBuIX3hHfhnK-NETDwTeFkbwaisO0Pz72XASgzoeGauFue6E1Vt8N_1aolF0yGgCUQCKpFHHNKXE4hiC5jOjffXbs_sn_JGtnWttUdvBOg/Jason%20Bourne%20Official%20Trailer%20%231%20(2016)%20-%20Matt%20Damon%2C%20Alicia%20Vikander%20Movie%20HD%20(2).mp4",
                    ContentType = "video/mp4",
                    Name = "Jason Bourne"
                });
            }
            else if (cardContent.Key == "The Land")
            {
                replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
                {
                                           ContentUrl = "https://fk5qxa-bn1306.files.1drv.com/y3mUNjU5jaVGRSYFQUv0Vt2Tged9t9HtB8OTT4yhtGFYQVW6l3LZTaqi-2UDLbCNZ9fYXIMBbwrPi7vFQx5mdkSgPkXwyAHQZF5FRu3h2lIA_GFqMVCO-u0OZ6q1hufxrzJyUfkI1FS6d8ziiL3ANoOu-urUdJcDcOyoWTICKlvp-E/The%20Land%20Official%20Trailer%201%20(2016)%20-%20Moises%20Arias%2C%20Machine%20Gun%20Kelly%20Movie%20HD%20(1).mp4",
                    ContentType = "video/mp4",
                    Name = "The Land"
                });
            }
            else if (cardContent.Key == "Yoga Hosers")
            {
                replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
                {
                                           ContentUrl = "https://fu5qxa-bn1306.files.1drv.com/y3mYZrh1Hxvu5Zffo2EDTI35N3Tuuce-Un-f5LaRmISDa9MMX-Q1sOD50YN2mPcGngVkGUJuFMGgPi98GJpRdhHiqHs3z-ZEvpxrD2zhus0u1LVdHcST3Oaay0TmE-7zxfmt1TFonYSSjsx4YJP2Y1T0UbNVjIrVU3nE7oZ5YX_D-Q/Yoga%20Hosers%20TRAILER%20(2016)%20-%20Johnny%20Depp%2C%20Justin%20Long%20Movie%20HD%20(1).mp4",
                    ContentType = "video/mp4",
                    Name = "Yoga Hosers"
                });
            }
        }
        replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.List;
        await context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);
    }
```

when I am calling in Skype, it's getting the video is like below and its playing successfully.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  I'm not sure exactly what you are asking or what you are expecting to see.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi  Lars
I am working on Bots using BotFramework. Here I have a requirement like I want to display the multiple video files on bots for that I am write the above line of code and when I am running my project in local its displaying the all the video files and when I am debug the code its getting all the data, so here my issue when I am configuring my bot to skype channel its displaying only one video content rest of the things are not showing, so how to resolve the issue for skype.

Comment: My guess is that Skype only allows one video per message.  Have you tried sending multiple messages?

Comment: Ya I tried but now I am change my code its working properly in the first time means it’s getting all the data but in the second time onwards I am getting only one video file content I can’t understand how to resolve the problem

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this bug.  May have something to do with the links you are providing.  See my response in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739618/data-not-predictably-received-in-skype-using-bots/38776747#38776747